# How can I disable constructor execution in Mockito/PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I need to write tests for `MyClass` class.

```
public class MyClass {
        public Result<Data> get() {
            return Request
                .buildRequest(session, Data.class, new DefaultErrorHandler())
                .executeAndConvert();
        }
    }
```

My Request class

```
    public class Request<Type> implements RequestBuilder<Type> {
        public static <T> Request<T> buildRequest(String session, Class<T> responseClass) {
            return buildRequest(session, responseClass, null);
        }

        public static <T> Request<T> buildRequest(String session, Class<T> responseClass, ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
            Request<T> request = new Request<T>(session, responseClass);
            // some logic
            return request;
        }

        @Override
        public Result<Type> executeAndConvert() {
            Invocation.Builder req = buildRequest();
            return executeRequest(req);
        }
        // some other code
}
```

Here is my code for test

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Request.class);
PowerMockito.when(Request.buildRequest(sessionMock, Data.class)).thenReturn(requestMock);
myClass.get(); // which is return a Request object
```

I want to disable Request constructor invocation because I get NPE when in firing inside. Actually I don't need to invoke all methods inside of constructor or in chain of methods. I 'm just need to return a mocked Result.

Comment: Use PowerMock to mock the static method `Request.buildRequest` and then make it return a mock instance of `Result<Type>` which then has an expectation for the call to `executeAndConvert()` which returns the `Result<Data>` that your `get()` method returns

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense to me as you're calling `buildRequest()` a second time inside `executeAndConvert()`. Can you make changes to  the `Request` class? This isn't really a traditional builder pattern and it's causing you problems as you are constructing objects in your constructors

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerMockito.when(Request.buildRequest(sessionMock, Data.class)).thenReturn(requestMock);
```

does not match the call you are calling:

```
Request.buildRequest(session, Data.class, new DefaultErrorHandler())
```

You should also add a matcher for the ErrorHandler. If there is nothing set, `null` is returned, as you say.